# Javascript Reverting

Tags: javascript, variables

I'll dumb it down a bit, but I have a bit of code in my site that shows some elements one way, lets say I had this :

"I have an apple"

I am using a bit of JavaScript so that when a drop down changes to, lets say, orange, the p tag is now written:

"I have an orange"

When I click submit on the form I have, that new value is being passed to a database, but the page is not refreshed. When I go to make a new entry, my initial value is:

"I have an orange"

But I would like if it reverted back to it's initial state of:

"I have an apple"

Is there a way to tell the site, once the submit is completed, clear all changes - without refreshing?

Here's my initial JavaScript:

```
function getRequirements(client_name,location) {        
var strURL="display/getRequirements.php?client_name="+client_name+"&location="+location;
var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('requirementsdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a listener to the button which sends your AJAX request and then reverts the variables back to their original state.

You could have a function called `revert()` which resets all the variables as required.

For example, using JQuery...

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $.get("myurl",function(data){
     if(data.status == 200){
       //Successful AJAX request.
       revert();
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM does not itself record changes and thus only keeps track of the current state.

Your own code could keep track of either the initial innerHTML of the page or the changes you make and after the ajax call, your code could restore the page back to it's initial state.  There is no javascript function to do that for you automatically without some sort of page reload.

It would not be hard for you to keep track of each element that you modify and what it's original state was and then when you want to restore the page, you just cycle through that list of elements and put the content back to the way it originally was.

Here's an idea how to implement keeping track of the changes yourself.  You call `markElement()` right before changing any element.  You call `restoreElements()` when you want to restore them all.

```
var changedElements = {};
var changedCntr = 1;

// call this right before you change the contents of any element 
// that you want later restored
function markElement(elem) {
    if (!elem.id) {
        elem.id = "_changeCnt" + changedCntr++;
    }
    // if we haven't already saved the state of this element, save it now
    if (!(elem.id in changedElements)) {
        changedElements[elem.id] = elem.innerHTML;
    }
}

// call this when you want to restore all elements
function restoreElements() {
    for (var id in changedElements) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        elem.innerHTML = changedElements[id];
    }
    changedElements = {};
}
```

You should probably only call markElement on leaf nodes (elements with no children) so that you don't run the risk of losing any event handlers when you do the restore.

Note: this code only handles changes to elements, not creation/deletion unless you call markElement on a parent node before creation/deletion of child objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you had it set up as a form field, you could just reset the form. If you don't want the user to be able to type, just add the `readonly` attribute, and optionally style it to not look like an input element anymore.